# Cat strings from file and compare it with associative bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

I create associative array for example

`declare -A vars=(["Test array here"]="POOLING TESTPOOL ")`

And i have file with multiple lines which want to compare with array values and if match print array key.
I try this but it's doesn't work

`match="POOLING TESTPOOL"`

`for key in "${vars[@]}"; do [[ $key = "$match" ]] && printf '%s\n' "${!vars[$key]}" ; done`

Also I try glob

`for key in "${vars[@]}"; do [[ $key = *"$match"* ]] && printf '%s\n' "${!vars[$key]}" ; done`

But every time I got empty string

Comment: `for key in "${!vars[@]}"; do [[ ${vars["$key"]} == *"$match"* ]] && printf '%s\n' "$key"; done`

Comment: Can you use zsh instead of bash?

Answer (score 0):

So if you want cat files and compare string with associative array value
and print its key you can use this nested loop

`` for i in `cat file.txt`; do for key in "${!vars[@]}"; do if [[ ${vars[$key]} == *"$i"* ]]; then echo $key fi done done ``

Thanks to @Fravadona to point me.